# How to get a pixel color under a magnifying glass eyedropper?

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, electron

For learning purpose, I'm trying to create a desktop eyedropper but I can't figure out how to retrieve the color of a pixel behind a magnifying glass following the cursor.

[image: Pixelmator magnifying glass]

In my head, I have to take a screenshot of the screen and display a zoomed and cropped version near the cursor. **But how can I take screenshots without the magnifying glass masking the part I want?**

I thought about masking the magnifying glass while I take a screenshot and then re-displaying it again, but it seems very shaky to me. How do other tools such as Sip or Kelir do that?

```
if (mouseCoordinates.x > offset) {
  hidePreview()
  const screenshot = takeScreenshot()
  showPreview(screenshot, mouseCoordinates)
}
```

I'm trying to do that with Node.js and Electron but I'm guessing platform specific APIs are necessary for that.

This is a matter of design rather than implementation so it could be with any language or platform: I'll adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my head, I have to take a screenshot of the screen and display a zoomed and cropped version near the cursor. But how can I take screenshots without the magnifying glass masking the part I want?

Why you want to take screenshot after displaying magnifier? why not take a screenshot before displaying magnifying glass and use it to crop and find pixel value in future, all you need is one and only one screenshot, so take it at first

When user move a thing o blur from your application, you must hide your magnifier, right? so when user focus on your app again, take another screenshot before displaying magnifier, this way screenshot always shows last state of screen

---

In order to capture screen you can use `screencapture` command on OSX, install `shelljs`, exec command and read created screenshot file

```
var shell = require("shelljs");  
shell.exec("screencapture screenshot.png", function(){
});
```

Comment: I would like to pick a pixel color from anywhere on the screen and not only in my app. I would also like to have the magnifying glass to follow the cursor. Your solution would work if the screen was static but what if the mouse hovers over something that changes when hovered? I'll edit my question to clarify.